# How to get Cox p-value for each gene?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

If you run the following code, you will have a data frame `real.dat` which has 1063 samples for 20531 genes. There are 2 extra columns named `time` and `event` where `time` is the survival time and `event` is `death` in case of `1` and `0` in case of `censored`.

```
lung.dat <- read.table("genomicMatrix_lung")
lung.clin.dat <- read.delim("clinical_data_lung")

# For clinical data, get only rows which do not have NA in column "X_EVENT"
lung.no.na.dat <- lung.clin.dat[!is.na(lung.clin.dat$X_EVENT), ]

# Getting the transpose of main lung cancer data
ge <- t(lung.dat)
# Getting a vector of all the id's in the clinical data frame without any 'NA' values
keep <- lung.no.na.dat$sampleID

# getting only the samples(persons) for which we have a value rather than 'NA' values
real.dat <- ge[ge[, 1] %in% keep, ]

# adding the 2 columns from clinical data to gene expression data
keep_again <- real.dat[, 1]
temp_df <- lung.no.na.dat[lung.no.na.dat$sampleID %in% keep_again, ]

# naming the columns into our gene expression data
col_names <- ge[1, ]
colnames(real.dat) <- col_names

dd <- temp_df[, c('X_TIME_TO_EVENT', 'X_EVENT')]
real.dat <- cbind(real.dat, dd)

# renaming the 2 new added columns
colnames(real.dat)[colnames(real.dat) == 'X_TIME_TO_EVENT'] <- 'time'
colnames(real.dat)[colnames(real.dat) == 'X_EVENT'] <- 'event'
```

I want to get the univariate Cox regression p-value for each gene in the above data frame. How can I get this?

You can download the data from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2p9dpw7AL_zMTNXR1JwRW1KRmM).

`Edit:` Sorry for not clarifying enough. I have already tried to get it with the `coxph` function from the `survival` library. But even for one gene, it shows the following error -

`> coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ HIF3A, real.dat)
Error in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge`

That is why I did not provide a smaller reproducible example.

Comment: please make your code reproducible--there is even a built-in lung data set you can use. we shouldn't have to do extra work or download data on 20 thousand genes from third party websites to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really going to do univariate regression for each gene of 20531 genes??

Guessing wildly at the structure of your data (so creating a dummy set, based on the examples in help), and guessing what you're trying to do with the following toy example.....

```
library("survival")
?coxph ## to see the examples
## create dummy data
test <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
          event=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
          gene1=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
          gene2=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1))
## Cox PH regression
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ gene1, test) 
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ gene2, test)
```

You may wish to use the following to get CIs and more information.

```
summary(coxph(...))
```

Hopefully that code is reproducible enough to help you clarify the question

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But as I have updated my question, even for one gene, the `coxph` function shows error.

Comment: So the question was really about interpreting the error message?

Comment: Hi, yeah, it was, sorry for my confusing question. But I found out the problem. As it turned out my columns were factor type, not numeric. That is why these errors were coming. But your example helped me to confirm that I was doing the right formula and the shape of my data frame was correct. In that spirit, I am accepting your answer. Thanks.